# Getting LocationManager and Longitude-Latitude null in Some devices like Google Pixel,Moto G4,OnePlus 6

Tags: android, gps, location

I try to get my current location with below code but it is return
longitude and latitude null or 0,0 in above mention device(Pixel os
8.0,Moto os 7.0,OnePlus 8.0).In other device with same os it is working fine.This is my code.

```
if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }

                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }

                            if (location == null || location.getAccuracy() < location.getAccuracy()) {
                                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                                location = location;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

> Get Last Known Location Method

```
 private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            Location l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
        return bestLocation;
    }
```

> onLocationChanged(Location location) method

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
                String add=addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)+", "+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the Fused Location API , which is a higher-level Google Play Services API that wraps the underlying location sensors like GPS.

**Usage:**

Add dependency in `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
}
```

Permissions required:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Connecting to the LocationServices API

```
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startLocationUpdates(); 
}

// Trigger new location updates at interval
protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    // Create the location request to start receiving updates
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    // Create LocationSettingsRequest object using location request
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

    // Check whether location settings are satisfied
    // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient
    SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

    // new Google API SDK v11 uses getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    getFusedLocationProviderClient(this).requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, new LocationCallback() {
      @Override
      public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
         // do work here
         onLocationChanged(locationResult.getLastLocation());
      }
    },
    Looper.myLooper());
}
```

and then register for location updates with onLocationChanged

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // New location has now been determined
    String msg = "Updated Location: " +
        Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
        Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // You can now create a LatLng Object for use with maps
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
}
```

For more info go through [guides.codepath.com](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Retrieving-Location-with-LocationServices-API#connecting-to-the-locationservices-api) guide